# HTML5 - how to align two canvases of different heights at the top?

Tags: css, html

I have two canvases inside one `<div>`. They are different heights and appear to be aligned at the bottom

```
          +-------+
          +       +
+-------+ +       +
+       + +       +
+-------+ +-------+
```

How do I make them look like

```
+-------+ +-------+
+       + +       +
+-------+ +       +
          +       +
          +-------+
```

I could make them the same height. But on a narrow-width display where they are vertically stacked, there would be extra space between the two canvases.

Comment: Are you asking how to align them to the top?

Comment: yes. there is no `align: top` option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're lining up on the same baseline because they are `inline` elements. Make them `block` elements (like `div`, `p`, etc.) and float them.

On narrow screens, they'll still stack up as expected.

```css
canvas {
  /* for display purposes */
  border: 1px solid red;

  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.container {
  /* for display purposes */
  border: 1px solid blue;

  /* make sure we contain the floats */
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas style="width: 80px; height: 50px"></canvas>

  <canvas style="width: 80px; height: 100px"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to avoid inline styling Paul.

Comment: I do, always, except when I'm forcing different sizes for a demo, and I don't want to confuse the demo-specific sizes with the CSS that actually solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

`float` is a solution, `vertical-align` with `inline-block` is the other (but note the space between them).

### Example :

```css
.container {
  border : 1px solid red;
}

.container > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid blue; /* debug purposes */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas width="200" height="40"></canvas>
  <canvas width="200" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
canvas {
    display:inline-block; 
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Please note that the use of `vertical-align` is dependent of the `display` property.

Comment: Thanks - odedta. This works!  BTW I do not understand the logic behind your comment on in-line styling.

Comment: if you use this property `vertical-align: top;` alone it doesn't work, you have to add `display:inline;` or `display:inline-block;`

Comment: @odedta, because `vertical-align` is applied only to inline-level and table-cell elements, What is wrong with that ?